# How to produce a message for same topic on different partition with null key

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I've just come across Kafka and new to it. So while making setup, I created 6 partitions [0,1...5] and trying to store Messages with a **null key** to the **different partition**.

For example:

```
var Config = new Dictionary<string, object> {
    { "group.id", "topic1_group" },
    { "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092" },
    { "default.topic.config",new Dictionary<string, object> {
                               { "acks", 1}
                            }
    }
};

var producer = new Producer<string, string>(Config, new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8), new StringSerializer(Encoding.UTF8));
return await producer.ProduceAsync("topic1", null, "Message1");
```

But when I try to run my producer class code, it gets stored in the same partition.

**Edit:**

```
Kafka Response: partition 4, offset 10
```

Now, the again producing the next message - topic1

```
Kafka Response: partition 4, offset 11
```

The servers and client are updated to Kafka version 0.10.0 and 0.9.0 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are returning the result of one send request.

Try producing messages in a loop rather than restarting the app, therefore restarting the round-robin partitioning